# Select an option on page load, with jQuery, and apply an onChange event

Tags: jquery, html-select, onchange

I would like to have jQuery select an element from "select option" and then fire an `onChange` event. I got it working for the first part (selecting an option when loading a page), but not for second part which consist of making the changes associated with selecting an option.

As you can see price from highest to lowest is the default displayed option. I want to make it from lowest to highest for a specific page only. I'm new to jQuery. Thanks.

```
<select style="width:175px;" class="lstSort" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lstProducts_lstSort" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$lstProducts$lstSort\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$lstProducts$lstSort">
<option value="PriceHighestToLowest">Price (Highest to Lowest)</option>
<option value="PriceLowestToHighest">Price (Lowest to Highest)</option>
</select>


<script>
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("select#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lstProducts_lstSort").val("PriceLowestToHighest");
});
</script>
```

The original ASP.NET code :

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lstSort" CssClass="lstSort" Width="175" AutoPostBack="true"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstSort_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Price (Highest to Lowest)" Value="PriceHighestToLowest" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Price (Lowest to Highest)" Value="PriceLowestToHighest" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("select#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lstProducts_lstSort").val("PriceLowestToHighest").change();
});
```

Or:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("select#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lstProducts_lstSort").val("PriceLowestToHighest").trigger('change');
});
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: @SpYk3HH: thank you for the edit, and trying to help, but please don't in the first few minutes. Many of us, myself included, post a preliminary answer (to solve the question), and then go back to edit, update, fill-out and add references to the answer. Which I was doing as you were editing. And not a problem, seriously: thank you for the attempt! =)

Comment: @David Thomas - Sorry it works but it's looping non stop. How to prevent this? I'm getting the page reloading forever and it just breaks everything.

Comment: What's looping, and why? If you don't show your change-handler I can't really help.

Comment: well it seems that the change event is executing forever which gets the page to reload forever too.

Comment: So *show the change-handler*, add it to your question then I might be able to help.

Comment: from where I get that? It's an ASP.NET page.

Comment: @David Thomas Well I think this is the event handler which can be found in my original code : onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$lstProducts$lstSort\',\'\')', 0)"